# ABAQUS using Python save a opened excel "Book1"

Tags: python-3.x, abaqus

guys:

This is the first time I ask question, sorry for the noob questions.

I am using the ABAQUS to do simulations everyday. After I use the Python script, it will generate a data from the ABAQUS about my simulation results. But after run it, it will leave a opened "Book1" excel file. I do not know if someone can help me that I could add some codes on the script to save that opened "Book1" .

I provide the last lines that how does the script generate that excel "Book":

```
chart = xyp.charts[chartName]
curveList = session.curveSet(xyData=xyList)
chart.setValues(curvesToPlot=curveList)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=xyp)
import sys
sys.path.insert(15,r'c:/SIMULIA/CAE/2017/win_b64/code/python2.7/lib/abaqus_plugins/excelUtilities')
import abq_ExcelUtilities.excelUtilities
abq_ExcelUtilities.excelUtilities.XYtoExcel(xyDataNames='From Current XY Plot1', trueName='From Current XY Plot1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abq_ExcelUtilities` doesn't seem to have an auto save option. If exporting data is of your main concern, you could do it without the need of `abq_ExcelUtilities`.

> xydata_object = session.xyDataObjects[*xyCurveName*]
>   session.writeXYReport(fileName=*.dat, appendMode=OFF, xyData=(*xyCurveName*))

Look into `session.writeXYReport` in the abaqus python scripting reference documentation for more information.